# Configuring SCons to use separate tools for code generation and assembly

Tags: python, build, code-generation, clang, scons

I am trying to prepare a build system using SCons. I want to use `clang` for the code generation phase and a custom compiler toolchain for everything else.

By default, the SCons configuration does not have an explicit step in which the assembly `(.s)` files are generated.

In order to get around this, I created my own `Builder` which emits assembly files.

```
code_generator = Builder(action = '$CC -$LOTS_OF_FLAGS -S $SOURCE -o $TARGET', suffix = '.s')
env.Append(BUILDERS = {'CodeGenerator':code_generator})
```

I then use this `Builder` on my source files and pass the resulting `NodeList` to the `Program`.

```
for file in Glob('*.c'):
  sources += env.CodeGenerator(file)

env.Program('say_hello', sources)
```

This works well when I do not modify any variables. I get an executable using `gcc`.

However, when I try to replace the appropriate variables so that SCons uses the custom toolchain (using `env.Replace(CC='clang')...`),  only one assembly file is generated. My custom `Builder` is not called on any other file and SCons tries to link with only one object file (which obviously fails)

1. How can I make SCons run the builder on all files and include those
   object files for linking?
2. Is there a better way to accomplish what I
   am trying to do? I am just beginning to work with SCons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a large number of keyword arguments for the `Builder` class that are documented on the SCons [man page](http://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-man.html#lbAO), that aren't mentioned in the user manual. This is one of the weak points in the documentation for SCons, and has been for some time.

In this case, I believe you are looking for the `single_source` keyword argument which:

> Specifies that this builder expects exactly one source file per call.
>   Giving more than one source file without target files results in
>   implicitely calling the builder multiple times (once for each source
>   given).

Looking at the source for `Builder` single_source needs to evaluate to True (or an equivalent). So your code can be rewritten with one very minor modification.

```
env = Environment()
code_generator = Builder(action = '$CC $CCFLAGS -S $SOURCE -o $TARGET',
                         single_source = 1,
                         suffix = '.s')
env.Replace(CC= 'clang')
env.Append(BUILDERS = {'CodeGenerator' : code_generator})
sources = env.CodeGenerator(file)
env.Program('say_hello', sources)
```

Which for a directory with the files: foo.c and bar.c produces the output:

```
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
clang -S bar.c -o bar.s
as -o bar.o bar.s
clang -S foo.c -o foo.s
as -o foo.o foo.s
clang -o say_hello bar.o foo.o
scons: done building targets.
```

Comment: Even after the proposed fix, I keep facing the same issue. But thanks for the remark about the extra documentation in the man page. You were right, I was only referring to the user guide. Will investigate further and report back if I am successful.

Comment: Which version of scons are you using?

Comment: Installed using Homebrew on Mac: script: v2.1.0.r5357
 engine: v2.1.0.r5357

Comment: I gave up trying to figure out why the Builder was not running on all files. To get around this issue, I created another single source Builder to construct the object files instead of using the Program Builder. Not the most ideal solution, but works well for now. Thanks!

Comment: I've tried to make it a bit clearer what the output that I'm seeing from scons is, but it's working for me with that version of scons on homebrew, with an older version of clang.